# SELECT hierarchy total without repeat CONNECT BY queries

Tags: sql, hierarchy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to show the `SUM` of a column in Snowflake across hierarchies in a single query, without having to perform a `GROUP BY` and then join *again* with the source table? Below is the query I'm currently using.

```sql
with
  hierarchy_accounts as (
    select id,
      parent_id,
      connect_by_root id as ultimate_parent_id,
      total_mrr_c
    from salesforce.accounts
    where is_deleted = false
    start with parent_id is null
    connect by parent_id = prior id
  ),
  ultimate_parent_accounts as (
    select ultimate_parent_id, sum(total_mrr_c) as company_mrr
    from hierarchy_accounts
    group by ultimate_parent_id
  )
select id, total_mrr_c, company_mrr
from hierarchy_accounts
left join ultimate_parent_accounts on
  ultimate_parent_accounts.ultimate_parent_id = hierarchy_accounts.ultimate_parent_id
```

Is there a way to get the `company_mrr` result in just a single query with the `CONNECT BY` clause? I'd love to just be able to run a single query like the following.

```sql
select id,
  parent_id,
  connect_by_root id as ultimate_parent_id,
  total_mrr_c,
  sum(total_mrr_c across hierarchy) company_mrr
from salesforce.accounts
where is_deleted = false
start with parent_id is null
connect by parent_id = prior id
```

Comment: We can try to use window function sum (total_mrr_c across hierarchy) over(PARTITION BY). https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum.html

Comment: Hi - it would be useful to know why you want to use a single SQL statement rather than the SQL that you already have which works: performance? Complexity of writing the SQL every time you want to use it? 

If the issue is that you don't want to have to write all this SQL every time you want to run this query then why not put it in a View so that it will always be available to query?